Standard error is too small on "perfect" data
While studying linear regression, I encountered this weird situation.
I am fitting a data to a linear model $\beta_0 + \beta_1 x$, and running a Wald test to check if $H_0: \beta_0 = 0$. Here is a simple Python function which returns $\hat{\beta_0}$, $\mathrm{se}(\hat{\beta_0})$ and $p$-score:
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

np.random.seed(0)

def test_regress(x, y):
    X = np.vstack([np.ones_like(x), x]).T
    params = np.linalg.lstsq(X, y)[0]

    residuals = y - X @ params
    n, p = X.shape
    var = np.sum(residuals**2) / (n - p)
    cov = var * np.linalg.inv(X.T @ X)
    se = np.sqrt(np.diag(cov))

    w = (params[0]) / se[0]
    p = 2 * norm.cdf(-np.abs(w))
    return params[0], se[0], p

This works well on data with i.i.d residuals:
>>> x = np.arange(1000)
>>> y = x + np.random.normal(size=1000)
>>> test_regress(x, y)
(np.float64(-0.035945884568210226),
 np.float64(0.06244021277994775),
 np.float64(0.5648282169352368))

p value is large, so the null hypothesis cannot be rejected.
However, is fails on data without residuals at all:
>>> x = np.arange(1000)
>>> y = x
>>> test_regress(x, y)
(np.float64(1.5683571961333255e-13),
 np.float64(1.1045055269032826e-14),
 np.float64(9.209482575035801e-46))

The $\beta_0$ is almost zero, but the standard error is too small so the p-value is extremely small.
The result is not surprising, and indeed it is unlikely to happen in real world. But in theory, how can I handle such scenario? Do I need to test for non-negligible $\hat{se}$ first?

The estimate and standard error are exactly 0; it is python that has led you to think they are "almost zero" due to numerical imprecision. Given that, it seems this is more a programming question: how can you prevent numerical imprecision from misleading you about the size of coefficients and their standard errors? In this case the true p-value is not zero but is actually undefined because the t-statistic is 0/0.

@Noah Thank you! Perhaps I should check if any of $Var(\epsilon_i)$ or $\mathrm{se}$ or $p$ is too small, like 1e-10...

The only problem here is dividing by zero, which is a problem with the standard error. So check if that is (numerically) zero; if so, return undefined values for the t-statistic and p-value.

Better software automatically issues a warning about near-perfect fit.  The moral here is when you are using a library like scipy.stats (or, really, just about any Python stats library) you need to know enough about the internals to protect yourself, because the library won't do it for you.
